# Iterate through all divs and search in any td if found fetch value of next second td value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, tags

Below is my html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html>
         <table id="table1">

      <div id="157">
         <br>
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td>Test ID</td>
               <td>:</td>
               <td>157</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Test Plan Name</td>
               <td>:</td>
               <td>Validation-Current Day</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>        </div>
                <div id="200">
         <br>
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td>Test ID</td>
               <td>:</td>
               <td>157</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Test Plan Name</td>
               <td>:</td>
               <td>Eligibility Current Day</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>        </div>


         </table>
      </div>
```

I want to search for "test ID" if found I want to get "157" same way I want to get Test plan name.I tried the below code but its giving "157" in case of "Validation-Current Day",Eligibility Current Day"

Below is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var resp = "";
var htmlstring = "";
var template = "";
var testIDArray = [];
var testPlanNameArray = [];

$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#Analyse").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
   url: 'home.php',
   success: function(response) {
    resp = response;
    alert(resp);
    $.get("new.php?&filename=" + resp).done(function(data1) {
     htmlstring = data1;

     $('<div />', {
      html: htmlstring
     }).find('div').each(function() {

        if($(this).is(':contains("FAIL")'))
        {
                 if($(this).is(':contains("Test ID")'))
                 {
                         testIDArray.push($(this).find('td:eq(2)').text().trim());
                         console.log($(this).find('td:eq(2)').text().trim());
                         console.log($(this).closest('td').next('td').text().trim() );
                 }  
                 if($(this).is(':contains("Test Plan Name")'))
                 {
                         testPlanNameArray.push($(this).find('td:eq(2)').text().trim());
                        console.log($(this).is(':contains("Test Plan Name")').next('td').text().trim());
                    console.log($(this).closest('td').next('td').text().trim() );     // this is also returning 157,158 where as I'm expecting "Validation-Current Day,Eligibility Current Day"
                 }


        }
     })

    });


   }
  });

 });
}); 
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

<button class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" id="Analyse">Analyse</button>

 <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm really stuck. Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

I want to search for "test ID" if found I want to get "157" same way I want to get Test plan name.I tried the below code but its giving "157" in case of "Validation-Current Day",Eligibility Current Day"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some changes in your html

```
<div id="157">
     <br>
     <table>
        <tr>
           <td>Test ID</td>
           <td>:</td>
           <td>157</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>Test Plan Name</td>
           <td>:</td>
           <td>Validation-Current Day</td>
        </tr>
      </table>   
    </div>

    <div id="200">
     <br>
     <table>
        <tr>
           <td>Test ID</td>
           <td>:</td>
           <td>157</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>Test Plan Name</td>
           <td>:</td>
           <td>Eligibility Current Day</td>
        </tr>
      </table>      
      </div>
```

In above html, If you want to add this html into table then you need to add tr,td as well.

Change your JS each loop code as below

```
$("div").each(function() {

    if($(this).find("table tr:first td:first").text() == "Test ID")
    {
      testIDArray.push($(this).find("table tr:first td:eq(2)").text().trim());
    }  
    if($(this).find("table tr:eq(1) td:first").text() == "Test Plan Name")
    {
      testPlanNameArray.push($(this).find('table tr:eq(1) td:eq(2)').text().trim());
    } 

 })

alert(testIDArray)
alert(testPlanNameArray)
```

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a ton @Prashant Patil

Comment: Hi @PrashantPatil this code worked. But that html file will be generated dynamically. tr td number will vary everytime. I want to search for "Test ID" or any string and then get 2nd td value. How to do this ?

Comment: Means 1st tr position is not fixed?

Comment: I got it done. Thanks a lot @PrashantPatil. Now I want to search for particular string in td say "Error". It should search on basis "match whole string" i.e., if other <td> contains "Errorrr" it should ignore that. How to do this. Can you please help me

Comment: yes! you can use regex for this.. you need to get text using jQuery("td").text()