# how to get font colour or text colour of td value using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting values of td if it contains "searched string" using

```
var t1=$(this).find('tr:has(td:first-child:contains("Error"))');
alert($(this).find('tr:has(td:first-child:contains("Error"))').css === "red"));
if (t1.length) {
    str =t1.text().trim();
    str = /:(.+)/.exec(str)[1];
    errorArray.push(str);
    // alert(str);
}
```

It is working fine. Now I want to add one more condition. How will I check for font colour of that. If it is equal to red then to proceed.Kindly help. If that can't be done then help me in searching for "Error" now how will I check using criteria **"Match whole word"**. Search only for that particular string if any td has. If any td contains "Errorrr" it shouldn't consider that.

Comment: If you could provide a fiddle of this working that would be great

Comment: I really don't know how to create that. Pardon me. Kindly help me how to check for font colour or I'm searching for "Error" now how will I check using criteria "Match whole word" like in editors. Search only for that particular string if any td has. If any td contains "Errorrr" it shouldn't consider.

Answer (score 2):

Check it... think, this is what yo need

```js
$('table tr td').on('click',function(){
alert($(this).css('background-color'));
})
```

```css
table tr td{ border:solid 1px; padding:2px}
table tr td:nth-child(even){ background-color:#ff3}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>first</td>
    <td>second</td>
    <td>third</td>
    <td>fourth</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53607434/iterate-through-all-divs-and-search-in-any-td-if-found-fetch-value-of-next-secon That is my entire code. I'm making get call and then reading contents from a html file. Not on click . I need to search id <td> contains only "Error" nothing else. If it containg "Error 1" it should ignore it. This is my request.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is without JQuery, using `getComputedStyle()`. With this function you can get the actual style that is, after all the cascades and overwriting is done, rendered on the page:

```
const td = document.querySelector("table tr td"); // you can use JQuery here, if that makes you happy, or whichever way to select the element from the DOM.
const colour = getComputedStyle(td).backgroundColor;

console.log(colour);
```

This way you can get any actual, rendered CSS attribute from any element. The only caveat is to replace the kebab-case with camelCase (`background-color` -> `backgroundColor`).

Comment: How will I implement this code with my piece of code. I have not used query selector and all. I have used $(this)

Comment: It's the same thing. The first line is not important, you can use JQuery on the first line (`const td = $(this)` or whatever)... 

The second line is the key.